# Showing a previously selected answer when a Spinner is reloaded

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am looking for a way to show a previously selected answer when a spinner is reloaded.

Currently, the user can select from a selection on a spinner control, this is set via a XML file. That selection is then written to a SQLite Database - this relates to a particular job.

The problem for me comes when I reload the data for the required job back into my app - I'd like the spinner to instantly show the previously selected response loaded back from the database.

Can anyone point me in the right place to find out how to alter the first shown item in the spinner?

EDIT: Added Spinner code I have so far.

```
// Terrain Spinner

        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTerrain);

        //I think it is here i need to implement the suggested answer

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {
            Property.terrain = adapter.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
        //do something else
        }
        });
```

I like and understand your method for finding the position of the matching array position - I could do with some clarification as to how to alter the adapter (as I don't seem to have one at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the position of the adapter in the Spinner adapter. `theSpinnerAdapter.setSelection(someIntegerIndicatingPosition);`

To get the position, you may need to do a lookup in your ArrayList, assuming that's the source of your spinner, to find the item and grab it's position. Something like this:

```
public int FindPositionOfItem(String itemValue)
{
    int itemPosition = 0;

    //Loop through each item in the list of spinner items
    for(String itemInList: allSpinnerItems)
    {
        //Check if the current item matches the item retrieved from the database
        if(itemInList.equals(itemValue))
        {
            break;
        }

        itemPosition++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then after you get the value from the database just pass it into that method to get the position.

```
int positionOfSelectedItem = FindPositionOfItem(valueCapturedFromDB);
theSpinnerAdapter.setSelection(positionOfSelectedItem);
```

**Edit**: If you are using an ArrayAdapter as the Spinner Adapter, I think you can just do `int position = adapter.getPosition(stringRetrievedFromDatabase)`

Comment: Gophermofur has understood what i tried to explain. Now i am just unsure as to how i should implement his answer in my code (added as an edit)

Comment: Show us where you how you gather your source data (whatever is being listed in the spinner), then I can show you how to implement my answer into your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `previouslySelected` column to your database, and then `ORDER BY` that field to get the previously selected answer to appear at the top of the list.

Comment: Hi Austin - Sorry i wasnt clear enough in my explanation.  The real issue is how to get the variable shown on the spinner - i am happy about how to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0):

I quite didn't understand your question very well, but I suppose that all you want is to select the item at the spinner just after you get the previously selected item from the database, that's right?

If so, you could improve on something similar to this:

```
        Spinner s = ...;
        Cursor c = getPreviouslySelectedItemFromDatabase();
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
            String property = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("previous_item")); // That's the column on the db
            c.close();

            final int count = s.getAdapter().getCount();
            for (int index = 0; index < count; count++) {
                String value = (String) s.getAdapter().getItem(index);
                if (TextUtils.equals(value, property)) {
                    s.setSelection(index);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

If you just want to mantain the spinner state across the UI, take a look at this:

```
        Spinner s = ...;
//After selected
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putInt(PREF_LAST_SELECTED_POS, s.getSelectedItemPosition());
        editor.commit();
//-----------------     
//At the moment you want to retain the state of the spinner 
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int position = settings.getInt(PREF_LAST_SELECTED_POS, 0);

        s.setSelection(position);
```